# ¿Por que | (operador o binario) trunca un numero decimal?

Tags: javascript

Buenas. Mi pregunta es bastante simple, lo muestro con este ejemplo:

```js
$('#resultado').append($('<p>').html(13.135345 | 0));
$('#resultado').append($('<p>').html(122.333 | 0));
$('#resultado').append($('<p>').html(56.43 | 0));
$('#resultado').append($('<p>').html(NaN | 0));
$('#resultado').append($('<p>').html('1233.5555' | 0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
    <p>Ejemplo de truncamiento con operador O binario</p>
<section>

<section id="resultado"></section>
```

¿Por que al usar el operador | en números decimales los trunca? esto lo vi en la siguiente [pregunta de SO en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24843735/6658955)

Comment: El operador or binario compara parejas de bits y el resultado es 1 si al menos un bit de la pareja es 1. Un numero decimal no se puede pasar a binario, por tanto trunca a la parte entera. Comparando con 0, el resultado es el mismo valor pero sin la parte decimal.

Comment: ... y es más rápido que `Math.trunc()` pero sólo funciona hasta 32 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los operadores a nivel de bit tratan sus operandos como una secuencia de 32 bits (unos y ceros). Cualquier número es pasado a entero en [complemento a dos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos) de 32 bits y luego operado.

Puedes encontrar más detalles en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators) o en la especificación oficial de [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)